# Problems with dynamically adding TableRow in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

My code:

```
public class Test extends Activity {

private TableLayout tableLayout = null;
private Button add = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

    add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.agregar);
    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TableRow fila = new TableRow(Test.this);
            Button eliminar = new Button(Test.this);
            eliminar.setText("delete");
            eliminar.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            fila.addView(eliminar,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tableLayout.addView(fila,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    });
}
```

I want it to add a new row every time I click on the **add** `Button`. My xml is the following one:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Column 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:text="Delete" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/agregar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:text="Add" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Every time I click on the `Button`, it does nothing.  Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem please add an answer to your question and accept it so the question becomes answered.

Comment: how to add buttons inside tablerow using FOR LOOP and then for every button there will be another TABLEROW that will hold three linear layout horizontal orientation can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> I found out that they can not be `LayoutParams`. If they are part of a `TableRow`, they have to be `TableRow.LayoutParams` and if they are inside the `TableLayout`, they have to be `TableLayout.LayoutParams`. Like the following one:
>
> ```
> eliminar.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
>             fila.addView(eliminar,new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
>             tableLayout.addView(fila,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
> ```